# Firebase one to one chat app structure and get child by value

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

I try to build one to one chat app with firebase and angular. I am using structure which recommended on firebase docs but I am in trouble with data retrieving.

```
{
  "chats" : {
    "one" : {
      "lastMessage" : "test"
    }
  },
  "members" : {
    "one" : {
      "rebel" : true,
      "redboy" : true
    }
  },
  "messages" : {
    "one" : {
      "-KS1R6b-1TdVASQL4tj7" : {
        "createdAt" : 1474288450158,
        "text" : "hgagagagaga",
        "userId" : "rebel"
      },
      "-KS1aZxqX3_PpjNdyiA7" : {
        "createdAt" : 1474291191857,
        "text" : "hhh",
        "userId" : "redboy"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How should I get user 'rebel' chats with firebase query. Or should I store chatIds on users' root.

This structure confused me without `WHERE` clause

UPDATE:

If I add chatIds to users' root this solve my problem but not sure it is true or not. Seems right way

```
"users" : {
    "rebel" : {
      "age" : 3,
      "chats" : {
        "one" : true
      },
      "name" : "rbl"
    },
    "redboy" : {
      "age" : 5,
      "chats" : {
        "one" : true
      },
      "name" : "rb"
    }
  }
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase Database console. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you are right I replaced it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Firebase (and most other NoSQL solutions) you will find that you often need to model the data for the way your application wants to consume it.

Your current data structure allows you to easily find the members for a specific chat room.

Technically you can query to find the chat rooms for a specific member:

```
ref.child('members').orderByChild('rebel').equalTo(true)
```

But this requires that you define an index for each user, which doesn't scale (since you'd have to add them manually for each user):

```
{
  "rules": {
    "members": {
      ".indexOn": ["rebel", "redboy"]
    }
  }
}
```

The most common solution is to (as said earlier) model the data to allow the query you want. Since you want to find the chat rooms for each user, you should expand the model to store the chat rooms for each user:

```
"memberships" : {
  "rebel" : {
    "one": true
  },
  "redboy" : {
    "one" true
  }
},
```

As you see, here we keep the *inverted* index of `members`.

Now you can easily determine the rooms for user rebel with:

```
ref.child('memberships/rebel').on('child_added', ...
```

I see that you added a similar structure to your question. The main difference is that I added it as a top-level structure. This is a common pattern with Firebase, since it makes it easier to secure the data and retrieve only a subset of the data.

To get more comfortable with this matter, I recommend this article on [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/).

Comment: thanks Frank this is very good answer for me, I will add mine to top-level as you suggest

Comment: I have one follow up question here for @FrankvanPuffelen, What happens when user redboy wants to send a message to rebel? Would redboy first create a new chat and then add that chat as a node in memberships/rebel ? Is this the correct approach? Will all this logic be placed in the client app ?

Answer (score 1):

yes you need to store the Chat id under the user's root with value true to retrieve all the chats followed by messages. Please follow this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/structure-data)